# How to join a 3rd table to previous SQL statement with 2 joined tables?

Tags: sql

I can do simple joins effectively but I am faced with the following complex SQL statement to join to a 3rd table to display the `HostName` in the results as well.

I would like to add the column `HostName` which exists in the switches table (`SwitchID` is the primary key and `HostName` is the column).

Current statement is:

```
SELECT  SwitchID, SUM(score)
```

I need to display `SwitchID, HostName, SUM(score)` in the results by joining the switches table.

I have tried many variations but cannot get this to work.

```
SELECT SwitchID
,      SUM(score)
FROM   ( SELECT SwitchID
         ,      CallStackDepth * COUNT(*) AS score
         FROM   huntandpagingfeatures
         JOIN   huntgroupmembers
         ON     huntgroupmembers.HuntGroupDN = huntandpagingfeatures.ListDN
         WHERE  IsHuntGroup = 1
         GROUP
         BY     SwitchID
         ,      ListDN
         UNION
         ALL
         SELECT IF( ucw.currentportid IS NOT NULL
                  , ucw.currentswitchid
                  , ucw.homeswitchid
                  )
                AS SwitchID
         ,      count(*) / 2 AS score
         FROM   userprogbuttons AS upb
         INNER
         JOIN   usercurrentswitch AS ucw
         ON     upb.userdn = ucw.userdn
         WHERE  upb.functionid = 30
         GROUP
         BY     SwitchID
       ) AS t
GROUP
BY     SwitchID
```

Comment: Start with formatting your SQL statement. It will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.SwitchID, SUM(score), s.HostName
FROM   ( SELECT SwitchID
     ,      CallStackDepth * COUNT(*) AS score
     FROM   huntandpagingfeatures
     JOIN   huntgroupmembers
     ON     huntgroupmembers.HuntGroupDN = huntandpagingfeatures.ListDN
     WHERE  IsHuntGroup = 1
     GROUP
     BY     SwitchID
     ,      ListDN
     UNION
     ALL
     SELECT IF( ucw.currentportid IS NOT NULL
              , ucw.currentswitchid
              , ucw.homeswitchid
              )
            AS SwitchID
     ,      count(*) / 2 AS score
     FROM   userprogbuttons AS upb
     INNER
     JOIN   usercurrentswitch AS ucw
     ON     upb.userdn = ucw.userdn
     WHERE  upb.functionid = 30
     GROUP
     BY     SwitchID
    ) AS t
JOIN switches s ON t.SwitchID = s.SwitchID
GROUP BY t.SwitchID, s.HostName
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery omitted for brevity:

```
select
    SwitchID,
    HostName,
    sum(Score)
from
    ( ... ) as t
    join
    switches s on t.SwitchID = s.SwitchID
group by
    SwitchID,
    HostName
```

Just add the HostName to the `group by` and done.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by HostName as well as switch ID:

```
SELECT SwitchID, SUM(score), HostName
--- skipping most of query for simplicity
    ) AS t
INNER JOIN Switches ON Switches.SwitchID = t.SwitchID
GROUP BY t.SwitchID, Switches.HostName
```

You could also use a subselect in the column list to return the host name:

```
SELECT SwitchID, SUM(score),
    (SELECT HostName FROM Switches WHERE Switches.SwitchID = t.SwitchID) AS HostName
```